# PHP mysqli_stat - not showing memory statistics

Tags: php, mysqli

Running:

- PHP 7.2.24-0 ubuntu 0.18.04.7
- MySql 8.0.22 MySQL Community Server

According to the PHP docs (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stat.php), mysqli_stat should show the following results

```
System status: Uptime: 272  Threads: 1  Questions: 5340  Slow queries: 0   
Opens: 13  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 0  Queries per second avg: 19.632  
Memory in use: 8496K  Max memory used: 8560K
```

However, when I try to replicate this in my code (echo'ing output), I'm not getting the `"Memory in use"` or `"Max memory used"` stats...

```
System status: Uptime: 2683242  Threads: 7  Questions: 203911  Slow queries: 0  
Opens: 551  Flush tables: 3  Open tables: 436  Queries per second avg: 0.075
```

Anyone know why the Memory info is missing?  Thanks!

Comment: No idea. It could be only available with libmysqlclient or with debug information enabled.